# How can I see content_script errors in the console of firefox 62.0.3?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am building a web extensions and in a content_scripts inject using the manifest file I can see my `console.log` but not errors.

```
  console.log("starting");
  throw 'I am dying'
  console.log("started");
```

And my console shows this:
[image]

How can I see errors?

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [discussion](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/console-doesnt-display-content-script-errors/23009/5):

> Firefox console only reports uncaught errors. Syntax error in content
>   scripts injected with `tabs.executeScript()` are reported to the
>   background page, and are thus not caught.

You can use the Add-on Debugger to debug background pages, options pages, and popups. However, its says that you can't use it to debug content scripts because in **`multipleprocess Firefox`**, content scripts run in a different process from the other parts of your extension.

To [debug a content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging#Debugging_content_scripts) attached to a web page, use the normal web developer tools for that page:

> - either select "**Toggle Tools**" from the Web Developer `submenu` in the Firefox Menu (or Tools menu if you display the menu bar or are on
>     Mac OS X)
> - or press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` (`Command` + `Option` + `I` on OS X) keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The screenshot I attached to the question is the console of page where the content_script is running, the one that I launched with `Command` + `Option` + `I`

Comment: You can check the discussion link that I have attached.